# Unable to write Mergesort code

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have written an implementation of Mergesort in Python using the algorithm as taught by Sedgewick in his course. I am unable to sort it properly. What is wrong with the code?

```
def merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi):
    assert isSorted(a, lo, mid)
    assert isSorted(a, mid+1, hi)

    for k in range(lo, hi):
        aux[k] = a[k]

    i = lo
    j = mid + 1
    for k in range(lo, hi):
        if i > mid:
            a[k] = aux[j]
            j += 1
        elif j > hi:
            a[k] = aux[i]
            i += 1
        elif a[i] < a[j]:
            a[k] = aux[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            a[k] = aux[j]
            j += 1
    assert isSorted(a, lo, hi)  

def sort(a, aux, lo, hi):
    if (lo >= hi): return a
    mid = math.floor(lo + (hi-lo) / 2)

    sort(a, aux, lo, mid)
    sort(a, aux, mid+1, hi)
    merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi)

def merge_sort(a):
    aux = [0] * len(a)
    sort(a, aux, 0, len(a))
    assert isSortedArray(a)
```

Comment: maybe you try to debug?

Answer (score 0):

Python uses 0 based indexing. You need to adjust your lo, mid, hi to 0-based indexing.

starting point would be

```
sort(a,aux,0, len(a)-1)
```